# Blazor WASM hosted how can I list all Identity Users in a Client page?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I can't seem to list the Identity users in a Blazor Client page using typical HTML.  The reason is, I can't seem to get to the `userManager.Users.ToList()` in the Client-side.

This project is VS-2022, CORE-6, Blazor webassembly hosted with a SQL Server database.

My goal would be to have an Administrator (role) to CRUD "employees".

The starting point for me is "list the users that are in AspNetUsers table".  I have been unable to do so.  I want to use the Identity: UserManager, RoleManager and Claims, but seem unable to get to these objects from the client-side.

I seek snippets of code that shows the code in SHARED, SERVER and CLIENT projects.

There is a similiar question without an answer at this link:
[How to list all the Users in a Blazor Webassembly hosted application with Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70534774/how-to-list-all-the-users-in-a-blazor-webassembly-hosted-application-with-identi) .

Your comments, questions and solutions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "list the users that are in AspNetUsers table".

The web assembly is runing at the client side, so we couldn't use usermanager to call the server-side EF core to query the table and get the user table's result.

I suggest you could create a backend web api or other page action and use the Blazor to call it.

About how to use Blazor to call the backend method, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server).

Comment: Thank you @Brando Zhang...

Comment: Thank you @Brando Zhang... I am inexperienced with C# and Blazor.  From tutorials, I have set up my application Repositories on both the SERVER and CLIENT projects to both GET and POST data from the DB that are functional.  Would it be a good (or bad) idea to create a "page" in the Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage folder by "copying" one of the pages like "ChangePassword.cshtml + .cs" so I can "fetch" the user list?  I do not want to mess-up the actual identity Areas-system.  Your comments?  thanks. John D

Comment: I suggest you could add the new page inside this account areas folder and provide the method. Then you could write some codes to call the page method.

Comment: Thank you @Brando Zhang...  I will try that and I will comment on my progress.  Thanks.

Comment: ...I have taken your suggestion and added a razor page in the Areas/Identity/Account folder that has access to the UserManager and I can fetch the list of users and display them on the UserList.cshtml page that I copied and modified from Index.cshtml.  Of course the code-files are modified as well.  In my Blazor Client app, I can place a NavManager item in the list below "Counter" and the page displays showing ALL of the users data.  It was NOT difficult for me to implement the html nor the C# code.  Thank you SO much.  You are very smart.